# In Humans, what are the hybrids?

Tags: humans

At the end of Humans, they discuss a new human-synth hybrid, but I don't really understand how it works. The season finale discussed the blood getting mixed, but that should have killed Leo. Also, why isn't Leo the first hybrid? They say that he and Mattie's child will be the first, but I thought he was technically the first?

Comment: Leo is a cyborg, until his blood gets mixed with synth blood. Perhaps Niska meant the baby would be the first born.

Comment: I'll return to this if and when I can bear to watch the season finale again.